# If my HVAC Fan Is drawing to much amperage will it burn the relay and the transformer

Tags: hvac, transformer

First I found My 24v transformer was dead, I replaced it and it burned out in 15 seconds apx. Then I checked all T stat and control wires they checked ok no shorts. The AC unit runs fin if I manually operate the contactor. The Magnetic relay that controls the furnace fan has a burned wire connector for the blue wire that feeds the fan controller for the Furnace fan. If my Fan is defective or drawing too much amperage will that burn the relay contactor or  did the relay burn thus causing the transformer to  burn. The HVAC fan was making noise last winter ( Knocking) but the squirrel cage spins freely.

Comment: Knocking usually means bad bearings or something in the fan(or fan housing) that is not suppose to be there.  Both can increase resistance to turning of the fan causing too much amperage.

Comment: relays should isolate the switched load from the controlling input. Typically relays are oversized and 20A wouldn't surprise me; thus your breaker would trip before the relay roasts if the fan goes dead short, ideally at least. Can you show a pic? If the transformer and relay burned, I suspect a problem with the furnace control board; shorting tstat wires is how they operate.

Comment: might consider inlining a car fuse on the transformer's secondary until you get the problem isolated.

Comment: No a failed fan motor won't cause the 24v transformer to fail. If you can include some pictures of the contactor, magnetic relay, control board, transformer, wiring diagram on the unit, etc we may be able to help further. Also please describe your methods for testing the T-stat and control wires.

Comment: shorting R to C  will burn the transformer